# Java xml parser passes wrong

Tags: java, xml

I created a java xml parser which almost stores the data succesfully, atleast first time its called. It creates version number, UTF and the "tree", which its supposed to do.

But second time the method is called, it simply creates a new "tree" and version, which it aint supposed to do (doesnt override, look attached picture!

What i need the xml parser to do is, first time the method is called, it will make the version, UTF, and the "tree". Next time its called, it will just add the data into a new "songs" node.

I apologize for my English, but i hope its explained clear enough. Else, please ask further in the comments, its easier for me to explain using comments! 
[link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKzT2.png)

Code:

```
public class Song {
List<String[]> songs = new ArrayList<String[]>();

public void addSong(String s, String a, String yt){
    String[] songarray= new String[3];
    songarray[0] = s;
    songarray[1] = a;
    songarray[2] = yt;
    songs.add(songarray);
    saveSong(songarray);



}
public void editSong(int i, String s, String a, String yt){
    String[] editsongarray = new String[3];
    editsongarray[0] = s;
    editsongarray[1] = a;
    editsongarray[2] = yt;
    songs.remove(i);
    songs.add(i,editsongarray);
}
public void removeSong(int i){
    songs.remove(i);
}

public String[] getList(int i){
    String[] j = songs.get(i);
    return j;
}
public void saveSong(String[] songl){
    try{

        DocumentBuilderFactory song = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder songBuilder = song.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document doc = songBuilder.newDocument();
            Element playlist = doc.createElement("playlist");
            doc.appendChild(playlist);

            Element songs = doc.createElement("songs");
            playlist.appendChild(songs);

            Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("index");
            attr.setValue("1");
            playlist.setAttributeNode(attr);


            Element name = doc.createElement("name");
            name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[0]));
            songs.appendChild(name);

            Element artistname = doc.createElement("artistname");
            artistname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[1]));
            songs.appendChild(artistname);

            Element youtubeurl = doc.createElement("youtubeurl");
            youtubeurl.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[2]));
            songs.appendChild(youtubeurl);

            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer tr = tf.newTransformer();
            tr.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            DOMSource dom = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new FileOutputStream("c:\\Applications\\staff.xml",true));

            tr.transform(dom, sr);

            System.out.println("done");

        }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
            pce.printStackTrace();
        }catch(TransformerException fce){
            fce.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IOException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

main method:

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Song Song = new Song();
    Song.addSong("This is", "A very good","Song");
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, it's that every time you add a new song you end up with a completely new XML document containing only that song.

You are creating a Collection of all of the songs you want to save, but when you call saveSong you are not using it. You're also making an element with the same name as the Collection, which is syntactically valid (thanks, scoping!), but a little confusing.

The easiest way to fix it would be to stop passing the newly added song in to saveSong and instead loop through songs (the Collection) and put the parts adding that parameter inside the loop.

So this

```
Element name = doc.createElement("name");
name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[0]));
songs.appendChild(name);

Element artistname = doc.createElement("artistname");
artistname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[1]));
songs.appendChild(artistname);

Element youtubeurl = doc.createElement("youtubeurl");
youtubeurl.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[2]));
songs.appendChild(youtubeurl);
```

Becomes

```
for (String[] songl: this.songs) {

Element name = doc.createElement("name");
name.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[0]));
songs.appendChild(name);

Element artistname = doc.createElement("artistname");
artistname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[1]));
songs.appendChild(artistname);

Element youtubeurl = doc.createElement("youtubeurl");
youtubeurl.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(songl[2]));
songs.appendChild(youtubeurl);
}
```

Comment: No, this is not the problem.. What i need is, that the program detecs: Is there a file called "staff.xml".. If there is, the method saveSong(); are going to append a child to "playlist node".. On the other hand, if there isnt a file called "staff.xml", the method will create the new file, with all nodes.. What i guess i need is, a method that detects if file exists when program runs, instead of merge "create file" and "add to file" in one method! Hope this was clear enough! And thanks for your help btw :)